# Iris color picker in custom theme option page not saving value

Tags: theme-development, wp-admin, color-picker

I have implimented the Iris color picker on my theme options page, but clicking 'Save' does not save the selected value, it just resets to blank (or the pre-set value). What am I missing here?

functions.php:

```
function accelerator_admin_scripts(){
    
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'wp-color-picker' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'iris', admin_url( 'js/iris.min.js' ), array( 'jquery-ui-draggable', 'jquery-ui-slider', 'jquery-touch-punch' ), false, 1 );
    wp_enqueue_script('wp-color-picker', admin_url( 'js/color-picker.min.js' ), array( 'iris' ), false, 1 );
}

add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts','accelerator_admin_scripts');
```

options.php:

```
function add_theme_menu_item()
{
    add_menu_page("Theme Options", "Theme Options", "manage_options", "theme-options", "theme_settings_page", null, 99);
}

add_action("admin_menu", "add_theme_menu_item");


function theme_settings_page(){
    ?>
        <div class="wrap">
        <h1>Theme Options</h1>
        <form method="post" action="options.php">
            <?php
                settings_fields("section");
                do_settings_sections("theme-options");      
                submit_button(); 
            ?>          
        </form>
        </div>
    <?php
}

function display_color_option()
{
    
        echo '<div id="color-box" style="width:50px; height:30px;margin:2px 20px 5px 0;"></div>';
        ?>
        <input type="text" class="color-picker" name="primary_color" id='color-picker' value="#000000" />
        <?php
}
function display_theme_panel_fields()
{
  add_settings_field("primary_color", "Primary Theme Color", "display_color_option", "theme-options", "section");
  register_setting("section", "primary_color");
}

add_action("admin_init", "display_theme_panel_fields");
```

custom.js:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#color-picker').iris({
        hide: true,
        palettes: true,
        change: function(event, ui) {
        // event = standard jQuery event, produced by whichever control was changed.
        // ui = standard jQuery UI object, with a color member containing a Color.js object

        // change the preview box color
        $("#color-box").css( 'background-color', ui.color.toString());
    }
    });
});
```

[image]

After save:

[image]

in header.php:

```
$main_color = get_option('primary_color');
```

returns blank.

Comment: Your color input is named `primary-color`. It should be `primary_color`.

Comment: @SallyCJ  When I change the input name to `primary_color` the value is stored and I can use it on the frontend. However, in the admin panel, the color value is still not stored/updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you've already [corrected it](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/375134/revisions), but as pointed in the comments, the main issue in your code was that the color input is not using the correct name as defined when you call [`register_setting()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_setting/).

I.e. The second parameter (the *database* option name) is the name that should be used in the input's `name` attribute.

```php
// The option name is primary_color:
register_setting("section", "primary_color"); // BTW, "section" is a too generic name..

// So use that in the <input> name:
<input type="text" class="color-picker" name="primary_color" id='color-picker' value="#000000" />
```

And there's actually another issue: the color input's value is always `#000000` because it's statically set so in the HTML, or that you didn't display the one saved in the database.

So to fix that, you can use [`get_option()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_option/) to get the saved value and echo it in the input. E.g.

```php
<input type="text" class="color-picker" name="primary_color" id='color-picker'
    value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_option( 'primary_color', '#000000' ) ); ?>" />
```

### Additional Notes

- If you want to use [Iris](http://automattic.github.io/Iris/) and not the [enhanced WordPress color picker / `wp-color-picker`](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2012/11/30/new-color-picker-in-wp-3-5/), then you just need to set `iris` as a dependency for your custom JS script — no need to enqueue the `wp-color-picker` style:

  ```php
  function accelerator_admin_scripts() {
      wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js',
          // Add iris as a dependency for custom.js.
          array( 'jquery', 'iris' ), '1.0.0', true );
  }
  ```
- If you want to use the enhanced color picker instead, then make sure to enqueue the `wp-color-picker` style and set `wp-color-picker` as a dependency for your script:

  ```php
  function accelerator_admin_scripts() {
      wp_enqueue_style( 'wp-color-picker' );

      wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js',
          // Add wp-color-picker as a dependency for custom.js.
          array( 'jquery', 'wp-color-picker' ), '1.0.0', true );
  }
  ```

  Then in your JS script, use `$( '#color-picker' ).wpColorPicker()` in place of `$( '#color-picker' ).iris()`.
- Your code is missing the call to [`add_settings_section()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_settings_section/), but I assumed your actual code has that call?

  And generally, it's a best practice to call `register_setting()` first, followed by `add_settings_section()` and then `add_settings_field()`. :)

Comment: That's got it running, thanks! And yes, I have the `add_section_settings()` call in my code, just did not paste it here.